# Haskell multivariable Lambda function for lists

Tags: haskell, lambda

I am confused on how this is computed.

```
Input: groupBy (\x y -> (x*y `mod` 3) == 0) [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

Output: [[1],[2,3],[4],[5,6],[7],[8,9]]
```

First, does x and y refer to the current and the next element?

Second, is this saying that it will group the elements that equal 0 when it is modded by 3? If so, how come there are elements that are not equal to 0 when modded by 3 in the output?

Found here: http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputlist/groupBy_f.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your second question: We compare two elements by multiplying them and seeing if the result is divisible by 3. "So why are there elements in the output not divisible by 3?" If they aren't divisible, that doesn't filter them out (that's what `filter` does); rather, when the predicate fails, the element goes into a separate group. When it succeeds, the element goes into the current group.

As to your first question, this took me a little while to figure out... `x` and `y` aren't two *consecutive* elements; rather, `y` is the current element and `x` is the *first* element in the current group. (!)

```
1 * 2 = 2; 2 `mod` 3 = 2; 1 and 2 go in separate groups.
2 * 3 = 6; 6 `mod` 3 = 0; 2 and 3 go in the same group.
2 * 4 = 8; 8 `mod` 3 = 2; 4 gets put in a different group.
...
```

Notice, on that last line, we're looking at 2 and 4 — not 3 and 4, as you might reasonably expect.

Comment: Hm. So does y iterate through the list? Are the groups created on the fly as y iterates? Once an element is placed into a group, does the iterator skip that element then?

Comment: Yeah, roughly. `x` is always the first element of the current group, and `y` walks over all the elements in the list. As chi points out, the lambda function is _supposed_ to compare elements for equity, in which case it doesn't matter exactly which element you compare against. The example you posted is a bit strange...

Answer (score 1):

[The groupBy function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy) takes a list and returns a list of lists such that each sublist in the result contains only equal elements, based on the equality function you provide.

In this case, you are trying to find all subsets where for all sublist elements x and y, `mod (x*y) 3` == `0` (and the ones where it doesn't == 0). Slightly weird, but there you go. `groupBy` only looks at adjacent elements. `sort` the list to reduce the number of duplicate sets.

Answer (score 1):

> First, does x and y refer to the current and the next element?

Roughly, yes.

> Second, is this saying that it will group the elements that equal 0 when it is modded by 3? If so, how come there are elements that are not equal to 0 when modded by 3 in the output?

The lambda defines a relation between two integers `x` and `y`, which holds whenever the product `x*y` is a multiple of `3`. Since `3` is prime, `x` must be a multiple of `3` or `y` must be such.

For the input `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`, it is first checked whether `1` is in relation with `2`.  This is false, so `1` gets its own singleton group `[1]`. Then, we proceed we `2` and `3`: now the relation holds, so `2,3` will share their group. Next, we check whether `2` and `4` are in relation: this is false. So, the group is `[2,3]` and not any larger. Then we proceed with `4` and `5` ...

I must confess that I do not like this example very much, since the relation is not an *equivalence* relation (because it is not transitive). Because of this, the exact result of `groupBy` is not guaranteed: the implementation might test the relation on `3,4` (true) instead of `2,4` (false), and build a group `[2,3,4]` instead.

Quoting from the [docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy):

> The predicate is assumed to define an equivalence.

So, once this contract is violated, there are no guarantees on what the output of `groupBy` might be.

Comment: Good point about not being a transitive equivalence relation. I had to actually look up the source code to figure out why the result is as it is.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I was surprised by that behaviour as well.

Comment: "Surprising behavior", otherwise known as "what code does when you violate its assumptions". ;-)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Sometimes this is called the GIGO principle, "Garbage In, Garbage Out". IIRC, even Babbage was asked (by a politician) whether his machine would have produced correct results when fed with wrong figures... ;-)